# How to force jQuery .append to clone events too

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/append/) state:

> Important: If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except for the last one.

I want to append resizing to some element and append this resizing handle to each row:

```
COL_TOOLS =  $( '#colTools' );
COL_TOOLS.removeAttr( 'id' );
COL_TOOLS.find( '.eCol_Manage' ).resizable({
    handles: 'e'
    ,start:  col_resize_start
    ,stop:   col_resize_stop
    ,resize: col_resizing
});

var cols =  $( '.eCol' );
cols.append( COL_TOOLS );

//This is WORKAROUND:
// $( '.eCol_Manage' ).resizable({
//  handles: 'e'
//  ,start:  col_resize_start
//  ,stop:   col_resize_stop
//  ,resize: col_resizing
// });
```

But when append do its job it seems clone is done without 'true' parameter because COL_TOOLS I have created this way are not resizeable unless I apply workaround.

Is there a way to force jQuery to do `.clone( true )` while appending?

Comment: `cols.append(COL_TOOLS.clone(true));`

Comment: append internally clone its parameter. This solution will make *only* last COL_TOOL to be resizeable